# Why is my Svelte component undefined in Meteor project?

Tags: typescript, meteor, svelte

I'm working on going through the Meteor tutorial using Svelte as my front-end library.

I am using TypeScript instead of regular JS (using `svelte-preprocess` as required, etc.) and I'm getting very strange behavior.

When I attempt to render a second component that's been `import`ed (Task.svelte), I'm given the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Task is not defined`

What is further confusing is that this error goes away if I `console.log()` the imported component before rendering it.

I'm convinced this has something to do with my TSConfig being screwed up (I don't know how it's supposed to look, I couldn't find a "proper" one in any documentation.) or something to that effect.   The components look fine to me, and this feels like it has something to do with how the component is being imported, and the Svelte template doesn't seem to think that it exists at all until it's logged to console.

I am completely baffled and would appreciate any assistance.   Below are the contents of a few relevant files:

App.svelte:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Task from './Task.svelte';
    // console.log(Task);

    const getTasks = () => ([
      {_id: 'task_1', text: 'task 1!'},
      {_id: 'task_2', text: 'task 2!'},
      {_id: 'task_3', text: 'task 3!'},
      {_id: 'task_4', text: 'task 4!'},
    ])
</script>

<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Todo List!!!</h1>
  </header>
  <ul>
    {#each getTasks() as task (task._id)}
      <Task task={task} />
    {/each}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Task.svelte:

```
<script lang="ts">
    export let task: any;
</script>

<li>{ task.text }</li>
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      /* Basic Options */
      "target": "es2018",
      "module": "esNext",
      "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
      "allowJs": true,
      "checkJs": false,
      "jsx": "preserve",
      "incremental": true,
      "noEmit": true,
  
      /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
      "strict": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
  
      /* Additional Checks */
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "noUnusedParameters": true,
      "noImplicitReturns": false,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
  
      /* Module Resolution Options */
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        /* Support absolute /imports/* with a leading '/' */
        "/*": ["*"]
      },
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "types": ["node", "mocha"],
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "preserveSymlinks": true
    },
    "exclude": [
      "./.meteor/**",
      "./packages/**"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Someone on the Meteor forums suggested that I add `preserveValueImports: true` to the options, but that didn't fix the issue either.